# Read from Google Sheet connection only allows first 100,000 rows

Tags: google-sheets-api

I can only read from the first 100,000 rows of any particular tab in a Google Sheet via the API.

Is this a known limitation of the Google Sheets API?  I didn't see a reference to it in the documentation.

Comment: About `I can only read from the first 100,000 rows of any particular tab in a Google Sheet via the API.`, if an error occurs, can you provide the error message?

Comment: @Tanaike there's no error returned, it just won't read past the first 100k rows.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks!  The spreadsheet can be accessed at 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19PVV5hWqiouEk1oGGcsgjRGEBJLjP3HToTOheH30kaE/edit?usp=sharing

And I'm just using a standard get request as defined here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue and workaround:

I thought that if you want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet, it seems that when the method of "spreadsheets.get" is used for the Spreadsheet including the large data, the data cannot be correctly retrieved because of an error like `Response Code: 413. Message: response too large.`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. And, in this situation, I confirmed that even when the method is changed from "spreadsheets.get" to "spreadsheets.values.get " and "spreadsheets.values.batchGet", the issue occurred. So I thought that this situation might be the current specification of Sheets API.

But, fortunately, I confirmed that when I tested to retrieve the values from your Spreadsheet using the query language, all values can be retrieved. And also, I confirmed that when I tested to retrieve the values from your Spreadsheet using the Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script, all values can be retrieved.

So in this answer, I would like to propose these 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are retrieved by the query language. I thought that in your situation, this might be suitable. The endpoint is as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###spreadsheetId###/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=###sheetId###&access_token=###accessToken###
```

In this case, the access token can be also included in the request header instead of the query parameter. At that time, please use `Authorization: Bearer ###`. When the above endpoint is accessed using your access token, all values are returned as CSV data.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values are retrieved by the Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script. The sample script is as follows. When you use this script, please test this script at the script editor of Google Apps Script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const id = "###spreadsheetId###";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Tab 1");
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(values.length)
}
```

When I tested this script for your sample Spreadsheet, `405028` can be seen in the log.

#### References:

- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)